# Extracting specific text from HTML using Python

Tags: python, html, text, extract

I obtained  the `HTML` contained in the file referenced below [1] executing the `Python` code below and entering the `URL` also referenced below [2].

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = input('Please enter the URL to get the HTML from:')

if url != None:
  response = urlopen(url)
  html = response.read()
  print(html)
```

[1] https://www.dropbox.com/s/5inyqpcpt7r7okz/html.txt?dl=0

[2] https://www.facebook.com/155210215241698/posts/490508308378552/

The `HTML` contains the text in the text file referenced below [3] and I would like to extract that text from the `HTML`.  I know that there are libraries like `BeautifulSoup` that might help me to do this, but I don’t know how to use these because I am new to `Python`.  Might someone help me by telling me what I might do to get the text for the `HTML` quickly and easily?  I would really appreciate it.  Thanks so much.

[3] https://www.dropbox.com/s/myy53zbfszidf24/text.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

For python, Beautiful Soup seems to be the simplest html parser, but you could try [jusText](https://github.com/miso-belica/jusText). Though, I'm largely convinced that using web scrapers on facebook is against their Terms Of Service, check https://www.facebook.com/robots.txt.

Comment: I didn’t know that about Facebook.  Thanks for pointing it out and for the information.  I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.  Thanks so much.